# Omit input data of map function in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, scala-collections, scala-2.10

I am learning Spark source code, and get confused on the following code:

```
/**
 * Return a new RDD containing the distinct elements in this RDD.
 */
def distinct(numPartitions: Int)(implicit ord: Ordering[T] = null): RDD[T] =
  map(x => (x, null)).reduceByKey((x, y) => x, numPartitions).map(_._1)
```

What is the input data for the map(x => (x, null)) function? Why and when the input can be omitted?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the [link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L318) to the source code.

Comment: Link to the source code?

Comment: Hi @Daenyth  Thanks for the reminder, I've added the link to the source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`distinct` and `map` are both methods on the RDD class ([source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala)), so `distinct` is just calling another method on the same RDD.

The `map` function is a higher-order function - i.e. it accepts a function as one of its parameters (`f: T => U`)

```
/**
 * Return a new RDD by applying a function to all elements of this RDD.
 */
def map[U: ClassTag](f: T => U): RDD[U] = withScope {
  val cleanF = sc.clean(f)
  new MapPartitionsRDD[U, T](this, (context, pid, iter) => iter.map(cleanF))
}
```

In the case of `distinct`, the parameter `f` to `map` is the anonymous function `x => (x, null)`.

Here's a simple example of using an anonymous function (lambda), in the Scala REPL (using the similar `map` function on a Scala list, not a Spark RDD):

```
scala> List(1,2,3).map(x => x + 1)
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

the map function `map(x => (x, null))` is the [map defined by the class](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L293)

I don't understand your question about omitting the input. You can't call a function in scala that expects an argument without giving it the argument.